# What text editor is used in the old CodeIgniter tutorial videos?

Tags: php, codeigniter, text-editor

What text editor is shown in use in the first CodeIgniter video tutorials? Here's the [link to one of them](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/intro/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an older version of TextMate.

The video itself is very old — you can see that not only is the editor in use an older version, but also:

- The CodeIgniter logo is different from the one we see today
- The OS shown is Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger

Answer (score 1):

That looks much like [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).